# Why cannot I reset UIView's frame when subview is added?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

okay, I add a plain UIViewController().view to another ViewControllers subview.

looks somewhat like this

```
public func add(Content vc:UIViewController) {
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.view.frame = menuView.bounds
    menuView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

menuView is constructed like this

```
public lazy var menuView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -self.menuWidth, y: 0, width: self.menuWidth, height: self.view.frame.height))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).cgPath
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 0)
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    return view
}()
```

The Controller holding menuView itself is constructed like this

```
let sidemenu = SidemenuController()
    sidemenu.add(Content: UIViewController())
    addController(vc: sidemenu)
```

Via a GestureRecognizer I should be able to move the menuView onscreen.
Problem is as soon as I invoke the add() function my view won't change it's frame anymore, although all hit test worked properly.

Repositioning is done via setting the view's frame including an offset

```
menuView.frame = CGRect(x: -menuWidth+_offset, y: 0, width: menuView.frame.width, height: menuView.frame.height)
```

Debug Navigator shows my menuView in it's original position at all times but no subview on menuView. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think the reference of vc is getting lost when you are passing it to the function because its not a global variable. put a breakpoint at `menuView.addSubview(vc.view)` and see if vc is nil or not.

Comment: @M.K. Exactly my Idea after outraging, writing this question and quit. I think vc is passed properly, but as it seems addchildviewcontroller() doesn't create any reference to the vc. It is released as soon as the function end (explain no error).

Comment: Okay that is not the problem. I created the Controller directly in the method and referenced to it via a instance variable. Same result.

Comment: Found the issue. I cannot reference menuView. It would always create a new view (check menuView implementation). Why is this?